# Renew conf/cert without stop/start nginx docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, certbot

I did implement a docker container with nginx, and can successfully renew SSL certificates with certbot. They are separated containers generated with the codes below.

They have an external folder to share documents, but I always have to stop/start the nginx container to apply those updated files content. Nginx reload command also doesn't work. If I go inside the container, files seems to be a copy of when the container first started.

At my previous architecture with VM, nginx would auto apply those changes.

How can I avoid restarting nginx container?

Create nginx container:

```
docker container run --restart always -d --name nginxXYZ -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 25:25 -p 587:587 \
    -v /root/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf/:ro \
    -v /root/nginx/nginx-log:/var/log/nginx/:rw \
    -v /root/nginx/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/ \
    -v /root/nginx/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/ \
    nginx:1.24.0
```

Renew certificate:

```
docker container run --rm -it -p 8080:80 \
    -v /root/nginx/letsencrypt/log:/var/log/letsencrypt/ \
    -v /root/nginx/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/ \
    -v /root/nginx/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/ \
    certbot/certbot:latest \
    certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot/ -d www.company.com -m "email@company.com" --agree-tos
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try reloading nginx:

```
docker container run --rm -it -p 8080:80 \
  -v /root/nginx/letsencrypt/log:/var/log/letsencrypt/ \
  -v /root/nginx/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/ \
  -v /root/nginx/certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/ \
  -v /path/to/host/script-directory:/scripts \
  certbot/certbot:latest \
  certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot/ -d www.company.com -m "email@company.com" --agree-tosSa
```

Save this script, e.g., as reload-nginx.sh, on your host machine in a directory that is accessible from within the certbot/certbot container.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reload Nginx configuration on the host machine
nginx -s reload
# Exit the script
exit 0
```

After Certbot obtains or renews the SSL certificates, you can execute the script from within the certbot/certbot container to trigger the Nginx configuration reload on your host system. You can do this by running the following command inside the container:

```
docker container exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "/scripts/reload-nginx.sh"
```

Comment: As I've metioned "Nginx reload command also doesn't work", therefore this does not seems to work on my case